# Hidden characters in string

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that deletes punctuation and spaces and then tests to see if the string is a palindrome, and to do this I wrote the code below. The problem is when you input a string with punctuation (unicode characters 49-30 and 58-66) it deletes them but replaces them with some type of hidden character. When I inputted "n on" it outputted "non" like it is supposed to but the length of the new string is 4 when it should be 3. What is this extra character and how do I get rid of it?

```
    System.out.println("Enter a potential palindrome:");
        strOld = scan.nextLine();

        int size = strOld.length();
        int start = 0;
        int noCap = 32;

        char[] cArray = new char[size];


        while(start<size) {

            if((strOld.charAt(start) < 48 && strOld.charAt(start) > 31)||((strOld.charAt(start) < 65 && strOld.charAt(start) > 57))){
                    start++;
            }
            else if(strOld.charAt(start) < 90 && strOld.charAt(start) > 64) {
                char c = strOld.charAt(start);
                c = (char) (c + noCap);

                cArray[start] = c;
                start++;
            }

            else {
                cArray[start] = strOld.charAt(start);
                start++;
            }
        }
        str = new String(cArray);
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str.length());
```

Comment: Have you tried using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)?

Comment: Your code will be simple if you use `Character.isAlphabetic()` or `Character.isDigit()`

Comment: Are you aware of all the static methods `isAlphabetic`, `isDigit` etc. on `Character`? The magic numbers aren't readable at all.

Comment: `cArray` size should not be equal to `strOld` if you are deleting some chars

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, it's better to write `'0'` instead of 48, etc.

Comment: Why don't you just use `String.replaceAll()`? It allows you to specify a regex and simply delete the unwanted characters to obtain a new String. That is way simpler than your current, character-based approach.

Comment: The way I chose to work through this was definitely much more complicated than it needed to be. I used the method suggested by Hemant Patel and Andrey Tyukin and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of this code, you have declared a character array as`char[] cArray = new char[size];`.This statement initializes an array filled with default char value `'u0000'`.So when you finally create a String from this array it will converts into a string which length is 4 if it only have 3 valid characters.

We can use ArrayList as the solution. We can create a ArrayList of character objects as follows.
`ArrayList<Character> cArray = new ArrayList<>();`
 This only creates an empty ArrayList object in the heap. Declaration of the size of  ArrayList is not necessary.The important thing is that, ArrayList can change the size dynamically.We can add elements to it using `cArray.add(c);`.

Finally to convert the ArrayList object to a String, We can use a StringBuilder object.  When we use ArrayList there will be no `'u0000'` default value.So when you input `n on`, the output will be `non` and the length will be `3`.The modified code will be follows.

```
    System.out.println("Enter a potential palindrome:");
    String strOld = scan.nextLine();

    int size = strOld.length();
    int start = 0;
    int noCap = 32;

    //char[] cArray = new char[size];
    ArrayList<Character> cArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while (start < size) {

        if ((strOld.charAt(start) < 48 && strOld.charAt(start) > 31) || ((strOld.charAt(start) < 65 && strOld.charAt(start) > 57))) {
            start++;
        } else if (strOld.charAt(start) < 90 && strOld.charAt(start) > 64) {
            char c = strOld.charAt(start);
            c = (char) (c + noCap);

            cArray.add(c);
            start++;
        } else {
            cArray.add(strOld.charAt(start));
            start++;
        }
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(cArray.size());
    for (Character c : cArray) {
        result.append(c);
    }
    String str = result.toString();
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(str.length());
```

Comment: Don't use an `ArrayList`, use a `StringBuilder`; it is built for this task.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong was in the beginning of the code I set the char array equal to the size of the original string. The char array was filled with null values, so if the string was "n on" it set the size of the char array to 4 from the start. I will try using the ArrayList method instead to fix this

```
    int size = strOld.length();
        int start = 0;
        int noCap = 32;

        char[] cArray = new char[size];
```